# nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color

Tags: android, webview

I need to show a page of a website with `Webview`, but page is all white and I get: `nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.`

Why?
I also tried:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

but I get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In manifest file set :

```
    <application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    .
    ./>
```

then in your Activity :

```
    webView = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else {
        // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
```